# Jquery Form plugin + Ajax (alternative to livequery?)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm loading a fragment of a page through an Ajax call. This fragment contains a form.

I'm trying to use this code:

```
$('form.ajax').ajaxForm(function(){
    console.log('tada!!');
});
```

which doesn't work since `form.ajax` selector does not apply to the content subsequently loaded through the ajax call.

In the past, I've used the "livequery" plugin, but I suppose there are more modern alternative to do this.

Are you aware of any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well livequery is a perfect sane way of doing so.

In the ajax callback which adds the content dynamically, you could also add the code which performs actions on the newly added content.